# Python - sending an email through gmail servers

Tags: python, smtplib

when I type the following code into IDLE it works fine:

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
>>> smtpObj.ehlo()
>>> smtpObj.starttls()
>>> smtpObj.login("email", "password")
>>> smtpObj.sendmail("email", "email2", "Subject: Test \nsent with python!")
>>> smtpObj.quit()
```

but when I try to make a program out of it to make for easier emailing it gives me a syntax error (error with two * on each side of it):

```
import smtplib

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()

email = input("What is your email?: ")
password = input("What is your password?: ")

**smtpObj**.login(email, password)

print ("From: " + email)
to = input("To: ")
subject = input("Subject: ")
message = input("Message: \n")

smtpObj.sendmail(email, to, subject + message)

print ("Email sent successfuly!!!")

smtpObj.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Python 2, use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

According to official docs:

> input([prompt])
>
> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.

In Python 3 there is only `input`

Anyway, you do not close parenthesis in input's `'password'`

Comment: ok, so i fixed that and there is still a problem. heres the error

Comment: 1. line 1 in (module) import smtplib

Comment: 2. line 46 in (module) import email.utils

Comment: 3. line 3 in (module) smtpObj = ("smtp.gmail.com", 587) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMTP'

Comment: The code you've posted (except for the asterisks) works fine here! You have problem with other part of your code

Comment: Ya, it also freaks out at
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) it doesn't know what SMTP is

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parentheses on the line before the `SyntaxError`. It should be:

```
password = input("What is your password?: ")
```

I feel comfortable saying that the most common culprit of `SyntaxError`s in Python is missing parentheses. What's slightly confusing to many beginners is that the `SyntaxError`, in this case, shows up on the line after the actual mistake. Just keep that in mind and always make sure your parentheses are matching.

Answer (score 0):

ok, after a little research heres what I found:

one of the errors I got was telling me to import email.utils. When I tried that it didnt work. Then I found out that my file name was email.py which means it was trying to import the wrong file.